# Looping in kotlin in line

Tags: android, api, loops, kotlin, line

i have some trouble in using kotlin for looping

i have json as like below :

```
{
idEvent: "584412",
strEvent: "Huesca vs Girona",
strHomeYellowCards: "28':Ezequiel Avila;34':Juan Nunez Aguilera;45':Damian Musto;88':David Ferreiro;"
}
```

and after i generate in android studio, i want the line `strHomeYellowCards` become like below in only one `TextView`:

```
Ezequiel Avila 28'
Juan Nunez Aguilera 34'
Damian Musto 45' 
David Ferreiro 88'
```

and these my code to make it happened

```
fun formatNumPlayer(players: String?): String {
        if (players.isNullOrBlank()) {
            return players.orEmpty()
        } else {
            val entered = players!!.replace(";", "\n")
            val splitted = entered!!.split(":")
            var result: String? = null
            for (i in splitted.indices) {
                result += "${splitted[1]}" + " " + "${splitted[0]}" + "\n"
            }
            return result!!
        }
    }
```

but the result is under my expectation, so how the true code about it?

Comment: Do you have any control over what format does the json come in or do you really need to parse it the way it is now? Because that is not proper JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON provided is not a well formatted JSON. So i assume that you just pasted the `key:value` pair here.

In this case, taking the value as a string and processing it would be the easiest way to achieve your goal.

```
// Assume bulkText is the value of key `strHomeYellowCards`
val bulkText = "28':Ezequiel Avila;34':Juan Nunez Aguilera;45':Damian Musto;88':David Ferreiro;"

var result = ""

bulkText.split(';').forEach{
    result += it.split(':').asReversed().reduce{ sum, element -> sum + ' ' + element } + '\n'
}

// result should be your desired output
println(result)
```

Comment: oh god, you save my time so much... thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all the JSON you provided in your question doesn't have correct format. It should be more like this:

```
strHomeYellowCards: [
  {
    "minute": "28'",
    "player": "Ezequiel Avila"
  },
  {
    "minute": "34'",
    "player": "Juan Nunez Aguilera"
  }, ..and so on
]
```

And then you can move on to parsing it. For parsing JSON object you should use a library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

Create POJO object for your YellowCard:

```
data class YellowCard(
    @SerializedName("minute") val minute: String, 
    @SerializedName("player") val player: String)
```

And then for parsing it:

```
val gson = Gson()
val yellowCards: List<YellowCard> = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<YellowCard>>(){}.getType())
```

Answer (score 0):

He can't use Gson because the minute:player pair is separated by ;
In a valid json this has to be a ,

If your really want to parse this manually, try this:

```
fun formatNumPlayer(players: String?): String {
    var result = ""
    players?.let {
        it.split(";").forEach { pair ->
            val tmp = pair.split(":")
            result += tmp[1] + " " + tmp[0] + "\n"
        }
        return result
    }

    return result
}
```